# Use different cPanel accounts for main domain and subdomains in same server

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, whm

I want to create a Cpanel account for a subdomain which the main domain also hosted on the same server.

" The domain “sub1.example.com” already exists in the userdata"

Answer (score 0):

There is a WHM tweak setting called 'Allow cPanel users to create subdomains across accounts'. Make sure this is set to 'on'.

But, the specific error makes it sound like the subdomain was already created elsewhere. If you have created a dns zonefile entry for sub1, or if you have already added sub1 to another cpanel account, you won't be able to create a new account of it. Make sure that subdomain is removed from any other accounts before you try to re-add it.

Comment: I tried this way I delete subdomain and create a Cpanel account for that first, but after creating a Cpanel account I couldn't create subdomain itself.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the entry for the subdomain from the dns zone file, too. If that fails, you might have to modify the /var/cpanel/userdata file to clean up remnants of the old subdomain.